# Wcf service refrence is not updating

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I had a operation contract with an int perameter, due to some reason I modified that to Guid and I update service refrence in client proxy project(it's in same solution).

But my client proxy is not update, it is still showing me the peramter as int. I also tried by deleting the service refrence and add service ref. again.

```
[OperationContract]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string application, string userName, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, Guid branchId, string branchName);
```

The branchId perameter was previously int.

Comment: Try to rebuild the project. Also, browse to http://yourServiceAddress/serviceName.svc?wsdl what is the type there?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all suggestions, finally I changed build output path from **bin/debug to bin** and error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check following things ,

1. You are updating the same reference , you made change
2. After modifying service , make sure your compile it , run it and host it again.

case may be that you have modified service in code but still referring the previously  hosted service ...

I hope it helps

Thanks 
DJ

[@debug_mode](https://twitter.com/debug_mode)

Answer (score 0):

Once your service is properly running, you need to run the [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool to regenerate the client proxy.